# CodeIgniter - active record - consecutive queries and time

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have this code in a model:

```
$this->db->insert($this->transaction_tbl, $data);
if($this->db->affected_rows() == 1){
   $new_balance = $result['balance'] + $data['amount'];
   $this->db->update($this->account_tbl, array('balance' => $new_balance), array('id' => $data['account_id']));
   if($this->db->affected_rows() == 1){
       return $data;
   }
}
return "error";
```

The code is doing what it is supposed to do (creates a new deposit transaction and updates account balance).

My question is: What if another insert/update query occurs (and does not affect any rows) right after the `insert` and just before the `if`? Will `$this->db->affected_rows()` still return 1 and continue with the update correctly?

In other words: Will 2 or 3 consecutive queries be executed consecutively even if a new one occurs among them?

If the answer is in the lines of: 
since `$this->db` is a different instance then it will not be affected then sorry for your time reading a not so smart question.

I am not familiar with the concept of time and priority in databases so i am not sure if the question is even about the codeigniter active record or a general database question with similar concerns

I am testing this in mysql if it matters.

Comment: $this->db->affected_rows()  always returns the number of rows affected from the last query......if an updtae/insert query doesnt affect any rows it returns '0'

Answer (score 0):

`$this->db->affected_rows();` always return the value of affected rows, but return 0 if it isn't affecting any row. And if you send a data in update query like this

```
$data = array(
   "title"=>"the title",
   "content"=>"the content"

);
$this->db->where('id', 101);
$this->db->update('mytable', $data);
```

and in your database

```
+-----+----------+------------+
|id   | title    |content     |
|-----------------------------|
|101  | the title| the content|
|-----------------------------|
|102  | any      | any        |
|-----------------------------|
```

the `$this->db->affected_rows();` also return 0, because you pass the same value on your database.